# Reseed identity column equal to record count

Tags: sql-server

We have int identity columns in all of our tables. We also have merge replication going on to support offline mode of the application, so we have to deal with identity ranges.
We are very close to running out of integer values (max value ~1.9 billion) even though the number of records are no where near to 2 billion, in fact the maximum number is little over 2 million. This happened over the years because of re-subscriptions of the clients and getting new ranges every time it did that.
Is there an easier way (least downtime) that I can compact this column to that 2 million value?

Comment: Why not just change the datatype to bigint and you can forget about it for a LONG time.

Comment: Or you could consider using negative numbers? Reseed it to -1 and make the step -1.

Comment: Using bigint or uniqueidenfier with newsequentialid() are other options. But int should be sufficient for next number of years given the yearly volume of data, so first trying to explore options to keep it as an int.

Comment: Well consider if you reset it to the current row count you are HIGHLY likely to get duplicates which based on your question I suspect you need to avoid. If you set it something less than the current largest value you are likely going to have collisions...nature of the beast. Not sure how changing the datatype to uniqueidentifier would help here. You would have to change all your external tables that reference this too which could start to get rather ugly.

Comment: Remember that an identity doesn't care how many rows are in the table, it is a count of the number of attempted inserts (it increments on an insert that fails too) and that having gaps is normal and expected.

Comment: And I guess the foreign keys are preventing you from going ahead and repopulating this table? Are you open to just pumping all data into a new DB and dropping the old one?

Comment: Pumping data into new db would be time expensive so as populating new column into table and updating all foreign keys which is what I was thinking of doing.